# C++11 source code generation

Tags: c++, code-generation

Is there some sort of library for C++ which contains classes which represents C++ source code?
It should of course be able to output the source code to a stream.
I'm looking for something which supports most C++11 features and is also capable of generating templated constructions.

When I google for this, I'm not getting the results I want. I'm sure though, that there is something available. Maybe I'm just using the wrong terms.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out the [Clang](http://clang.llvm.org/) compiler which uses a [library-based architecture](http://clang.llvm.org/features.html#libraryarch)  to support implementing IDEs and other tools that need to process the AST. Clang fully supports all C++11 features (and some C++1y features)

More information can be found in the [Clang documentation](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/Tooling.html). Or in [this blog](http://eli.thegreenplace.net/2012/06/08/basic-source-to-source-transformation-with-clang/) which describes basic source to source transformations using [`clang::Rewriter`](http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1Rewriter.html).

Comment: OP means **"...able to output the source code to a stream"**, so the question is not about generating AST or machine-code at run-time but generating **c++** code at runtime.

Comment: Thanks! Seems like it's capable of representing the whole AST. But I can't find anything about generating source code. And I don't mean IR.

Comment: @eznme He asked about "classes which represents C++ source code", i.e., an AST. And Clang does support converting the AST back to source code.

Comment: @Joe Thanks, very interesting! I didn't know that Clang supported rewriting AST representations. Just perfect.

Answer (score 0):

This is still in a very experimental phase, but in our lab we are developing a tool (Clava), which is based on Clang and uses a Javascript-like language to query and transform a given C/C++ code. It will be made open-source by the end of August 2017.

For instance, the current default example in the demo website reads all classes and structures in the C/C++ code and creates a C++/H pair with HDF5 wrappers for those classes (however, that code generation is a mix between AST and String literals).

([Clava - Online Demo](http://specs.fe.up.pt/tools/clava/))