# Generating code without templates

Tags: c++, c++11

I am currently trying to generate a C++ wrapper for OpenGL shaders at compile time. My current implementation uses templates but none of my co-workers could read it anymore and it also forced all of the code into the header.

Now I am wondering if there is a better way? I recently watched a talk about game development where the guy said that they never use templates in their engine and that there are much better ways to do code generation.

Honestly I haven't found something that works for me and most code generation tools are written in different languages.

I am wondering if there is something that looks like this:

```
auto foo_class = create_class().setName("Foo");
                               .addMember<int>("i1")
                               .addMethod("print",||(){std::cout<< "hello";});
foo_class.generate();
```

which would generate

```
class Foo{
  int i1;
  void print();
  ....
};

void Foo::print(){ std::cout << "hello";}
```

That way I could create a separate tool that I could just invoke at compile time. Does something similar exist?

Comment: What do you hoping to gain writing a C++ wrapper for what is essentially a C library? My personal suggestion is that you have code the wraps the higher level functionality which in turn references the lower level C-based raw OpenGL.

Comment: @ButchDean I am not writing a C++ Wrapper, I want to generate it. The main reasons are type safety and convenience.

Comment: See clang answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17339810/c11-source-code-generation

Comment: Apologies, I meant generating - my mind locked on 'writing' for some reason. Back to the issue, I think you are overcomplicating matters that could bring bigger problems down the road. One of my golden rules when approaching a problem is that if you have to think too much there is a better solution somewhere, or it isn't practical. I would look to careful programming for your type safety rather than trying to automate it.

Comment: possibly a #define with varargs?

Comment: This seems like an awful lot of effort to support your coworkers who refuse to learn modern c++...

Comment: You could try writing cleaner templates.

Comment: You may look at [ctemplate](https://code.google.com/p/ctemplate/) to generate text/code from C++.

Comment: You could write a tool in C++ (or otherwise) to generate the source code and make that code generation a preliminary stage in your build.

Comment: If the templates solution you have constructed is a good one, then instead of dumbing down the code, I'd suggest elevating the capabilities of your co-workers.  I know that's a tough road to hoe, but it's worth the effort in the long run.